# How to create and close SOCKS5 tunnel after n seconds?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, shell

I'm creating SOCKS 5 tunnel via ssh:

```
ssh -D 1337 -f -C -c blowfish -q -N user@host
```

I only need it for a fast and loose client connection, and then it's no longer needed.

I would like it to close after x seconds of being active automatically. I've tried postfixing `sleep 10`, which would potentially even stay open till a connected client disconnects, but otherwise closes after 10 seconds.

When I run this:
`ssh -D 1337 -f -C -c blowfish -q -N user@host sleep 10` the tunnel never closes.

I could sleep 10 in the bash script then find the process and kill it, but I was under the impression it could be simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try without `-N`. Maybe you meant `-n`, but that is implied by `-f`.